# Java use httpclient 4.1 crawl https get bad_record_mac

Tags: java, ssl, https, httpclient

Using the following code to crawl https websites, working fine on most sites but didn't work on some websites such as grubhub.com.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLException;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.X509HostnameVerifier;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class TestSsl {

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        TestSsl t = new TestSsl();
        t.init();
        t.queryData();
    }

    private void init() {
        httpclient = wrapClient(httpclient);
        httpclient.getParams()
                .setIntParameter("http.socket.timeout", 30 * 1000);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private void queryData() throws Exception {
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://www.grubhub.com/browse/");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        System.out.println(result);
        EntityUtils.consume(entity);

    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param base
     * @return
     */
    public static HttpClient wrapClient(HttpClient base) {
        try {
            SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            X509TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs,
                        String string) {
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs,
                        String string) {
                }

                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }
            };
            X509HostnameVerifier verifier = new X509HostnameVerifier() {

                @Override
                public void verify(String string, SSLSocket ssls) throws IOException {
                }

                @Override
                public void verify(String string, X509Certificate xc) throws SSLException {
                }

                @Override
                public void verify(String string, String[] strings, String[] strings1) throws SSLException {
                }

                @Override
                public boolean verify(String string, SSLSession ssls) {
                    return true;
                }
            };

            ctx.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
            SSLSocketFactory ssf = new SSLSocketFactory(ctx);
            ssf.setHostnameVerifier(verifier);
            ClientConnectionManager ccm = base.getConnectionManager();
            SchemeRegistry sr = ccm.getSchemeRegistry();
            sr.register(new Scheme("https", ssf, 443));
            return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, base.getParams());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I even set the following on jvm: -Djavax.net.debug=all -Dhttps.protocols=SSLv3 -Dforce.http.jre.executor=true

main, READ: SSLv3 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV SSLv3 ALERT:  fatal, bad_record_mac
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: bad_record_mac
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: bad_record_mac

I have researched around and put a bunch of stuff in the code but still no luck. Debug output is too large to post here, but can easily reproduce by creating a new class in your IDE and run it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

youre experiencing a known issue with the jre trying to talk TLS to a server that doesnt support it. see more info [here](https://support.sonatype.com/entries/22070546-deploy-fails-with-received-fatal-alert-bad-record-mac).

the suggested work around is to force sslv3.
unfortunately, trying to do it with system properties doesnt work, so you need to do it by by setting the enabled protocols to SSLv3 on every socket.

here's a small application that works for your host:

```
String urlString = "https://www.grubhub.com/browse/";
URL url = new URL(urlString);
SSLSocketFactory factory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(url.getHost(), 443);
socket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[]{"SSLv3"}); // <--- THIS IS THE WORK-AROUND
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(
                socket.getOutputStream()));
out.println("GET " + urlString + " HTTP/1.1");
out.println();
out.flush();

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

String line;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}

out.close();
in.close();
```

you need to override HttpClient's SSLSocketFactory with one that configures every socket like this:

```
socket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[]{"SSLv3"});
```

Comment: I did set this but didn't help. Please give it a try and let me know if it works for you, maybe something is wrong with my env. Thanks.

Comment: @xigua - youre right. setting the properties didnt work. i've updated my answer with a working solution